Meaning of Icon Used in Outlook Web App
In the last week, I noticed an unfamiliar icon appearing in the Drafts folder in my Outlook Web App account. Here is a screen grab (the icon is very small):

This icon appears against listings for draft emails stored in said folder (a single line is depicted below):

I searched and could not find an icon glossary for this application.
Any clues as to the meaning of the mystery icon?

It’s a contact icon, so something associated with contacts, probably means the sender or recipient is in your contacts

@Ramhound Thought the same, but no combination of addressing I've tried presents that icon for me.  Internal contact, external, attaching a contact.  I can't make it show up...

@Ramhound Interesting! I noticed that, in each instance in the Drafts folder where said mystery icon appears, the "Subject" of the draft email is the name of someone in my Outlook Contacts list...

@Digger Nothing happens if you hover over or click the icon?

@squillman Nothing happens with a hover. If I click on said icon, I get a page whereby I can further compose the draft email. This is the same action that occurs if I click on other emails extant in said Drafts folder that don't have said icon. If it matters, I'm currently using Firefox ESR 115.12.0esr (under Debian Buster)...
